# I am trying to use Balacoon-tts to convert text to speech. I can install it well on Linux but when I want to install it on windows, it returns error

Tags: python, installation, pip, text-to-speech

```
pip install -i https://pypi.fury.io/balacoon/ balacoon-tts
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.fury.io/balacoon/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement balacoon-tts (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for balacoon-tts
```

is it even possible to use this package on windows?

I have tried different python versions but none of them worked.

Comment: https://pypi.fury.io/balacoon/balacoon-tts <- Only linux packages.

Answer (score 0):

Its not for windows, You can install on linux easily using command:

`pip install -i https://pypi.fury.io/balacoon/ balacoon-tts`